# C# Console Application HttpClient throws "System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred"

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, dotnet-httpclient, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a C# console app with .Net framework 4.6 running within Windows Server 2012 R2. I was working with "IIS Crypto 3.1" to change some settings in the security protocols but right after using a feature called "Best Practices" in "IIS Crypto" (that automatically sets client and server protocols), I cannot get my application calling any URL through HttpClient again(it used to work before this). Here is my code:

```
 using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
  {
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, 
       errors) => { return true; };
       var response = await hc.GetAsync(download_path);
       content = response.Content;
   }
```

This is the exception I get right after hitting "hc.GetAsync()" :

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateExc
eption: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpExcepti
on: A security error occurred
```

and this is the current setting for my security protocols:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't know how to revert the settings I changed here(this app changes some registry keys).

**Update:**

So the problem appears to be only when calling a specific URL for Telegram Bot API (it goes like https://api.telegram.org/.....). For other URLs (as far as I could check) this whole new settings would still work. I must say that the previous settings would perfectly work with this very same URL.

Comment: download_path..... is this https? or just http?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro yeah it is an https address for Telegram Bot API. I actually just spotted the problem after 7 hours of continuous trial. I will update the post and answer correspondingly. In short, the problem was with "cipher suites" order which I had changed after using "IIS Crypto". Reverting the changes to the default order will sort the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 7 hours of continuous struggle, I finally found the problem. Apparently "IIS Crypto" had changed the order of "Cipher Suites" in the windows server 2012 R2. I was only enabling/disabling the protocols themselves, not their cipher orders. After changing the order of cipher suites to its default order ( note that this order is OS-specific. So it varies in Windows Server 2008, 2012, 2016,... And I found the default values in "IIS Crypto" webpage.)
It seems as though that Telegram servers are sensitive to the order of cipher suites and do not respond when changed (I don't know the exact technicals here). So this is how it must look like in Windows Server 2012 R2:

[image]

Moreover, I checked IIS Crypto in my laptop running windows 10 and after using the very same feature(i.e, "best practices"), I didn't run into any problem whatsoever. So this problem seems to be somehow related to the Windows Server 2012 R2